# Adding bands to imageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

With single images, `addBands` works, but what about an imageCollection?

[Code for the problem i am talking about](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e126917d396da191fdcd90720d6807f)

In this code, I have generated drought indices with variable names, VCI, TCI, PCI, VHI, SMCI, and Arid.
All these variables hold imageCollections with single bands. Now I want to compile them into a single imageCollection, but have no clue on how to achieve this goal.

Comment: collection1.merge(collection2) ? Or do you want some merging of the collections based on e.g. the time? Please specifiy what the actual problem is, reduce the code the a minimal necesarry and add a snippet of the code in the question.

Comment: I have already tried with merge and combine and add. Neither of these functions works. 
I just want them compiled in a separate image collection.
As for reducing the code, i already reduced it to the variables and their data (250 lines). The real code is 2000 lines long.

Comment: var merged = VCI.merge(TCI).merge(PCI).merge(VHI).merge(SMCI).merge(Arid);
 is not your desired solution? If so, explain better what you want?

Comment: With merge command, the image collection i get has only one band (Result displayed with print command).
I wanted an image collection which showed all the bands.
I got the answer i was looking for on my own. I had to develop a small function for it.
Thanks for your input anyway. I did wanted merging the collection based on time.

Comment: How about sharing the solution? :)